# Trying to pass PIL image to a function, getting TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

I would appreciate any help on this.

I am getting the error TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable.

I am simply trying to pass an image returned from PIL Image.open and then converting to 'RGB' to do some simple pixel manipulations. There are probably some other(even better) ways to do this but I would like to know if this can be done.
Thanks,
Paul

```
def reduce_color(image):   
    width, height = image.size()
```

```
img=Image.open("junk.gif")
img=img.convert('RGB')
new_image = reduce_color(img)  ----> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding where the exception is coming from. It's not your call to `reduce_color` that's causing the exception, but the code *within* that function. You're trying to call `img.size()`, but the size attribute of a PIL `Image` object is a property that returns a tuple, not a function.

So use `width, height = image.size` (without the `()` at the end) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have caught that. Much appreciated.

Comment: i think this: 'So use width, height = image.size (without the () at the end) and it should work. ' was a sufficient answer. Not the paragraph above. Its not our fault that open source stuff decided to change using () and not using () at some point...